# Download XML file by visiting link

Tags: xml, file, download

I have an XML file that is only available by going to domain.com/file.xml. When someone visits the link I want it do be downloaded and not opened in the browser. There will be no physical link to this, just the domain link that has to be put in the address bar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to specify specific headers, for example using PHP.
The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) provides a nice example:

```
<?php
$file = 'file.xml';

if (!file_is_readable($file)) {
    return;
}

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

ob_end_clean();
readfile($file);
```

Add the code above to `download.php` and upload the file to the `file.xml` directory.
Now you can download the file by visiting `domain.com/download.php`.
This is the best cross browser compatible solution.
Other server side languages can also do the job.

Comment: Nice one, this worked a treat. Thanks for the explanation as well, it really helped. Thanks.